# how to perform log+1 transform on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, logging

Please someone can help me with how to do log+1 transformation on multiple columns in R.

I have several numeric columns,

example (sp1, sp2, sp3, sp3........) up to 65.

want to perform log+1 transformation on 65 columns. Is any option available in R to transform the entire data set?  instead of transforming every single column.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please review the section How to Ask Questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Also, can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

`log` can be applied directly on the dataset

```
df2 <- log(df1) + 1
```

-reproducible example

```
 data(mtcars)
 log(head(mtcars)) + 1
```